# Domain Joining through Command Prompt: AWS

Tags: linux, windows, dns, active-directory, command-prompt

Getting some error while joining Domain through Windows Command prompt,
Command:

`netdom join %computername% /Domain:tens.com /Userd:Administrator /Passwordd:*`

The error is:

> The computer rename attempt failed with error 1355.
>
> The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

[image]

Same in Linux also.

Please help out to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. In addition, the text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means what it says: the computer cannot contact the domain. Is there a firewall blocking access to the domain?

These ports must be open from you to the domain, as described here: http://powershell365.com/2016/01/19/firewall-ports-required-to-join-ad-domain/

> Server LAN to Client LAN – Only allow Ping Traffics (ICMP Type 8,
>   Code:255)
>
> Client LAN to Server LAN – Only allow
>
> TCP : 88, 135, 139, 389, 445, 49152-65535 (High Ports)
>
> UDP : 53, 123, 137, 138, 389, 123 , 49152-65536 (High Ports)

You can test these connections in PowerShell. For example:

```
Test-NetConnection tens.com -Port 88
```

Comment: thanks. Opened all these ports in aws security group. its working fine @Gabriel